# scraping with selenium and undetected_chromedriver in docker container mac crashing

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, selenium-webdriver

I was attempting to run undetected-chromedriver in a docker container on my m1 mac and received the following stack trace:

```
2024-02-11 13:20:04 
2024-02-11 13:20:04 Scraping Pararius...
2024-02-11 13:20:05 Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-02-11 13:20:05   File "/app/main.py", line 42, in <module>
2024-02-11 13:20:05     scrape_pararius(logger)
2024-02-11 13:20:05   File "/app/scrape_pararius.py", line 25, in scrape_pararius
2024-02-11 13:20:05     driver = uc.Chrome(options=set_undetected_chrome_options())
2024-02-11 13:20:05   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py", line 466, in __init__
2024-02-11 13:20:05     super(Chrome, self).__init__(
2024-02-11 13:20:05   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
2024-02-11 13:20:05     super().__init__(
2024-02-11 13:20:05   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 53, in __init__
2024-02-11 13:20:05     self.service.start()
2024-02-11 13:20:05   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 102, in start
2024-02-11 13:20:05     self.assert_process_still_running()
2024-02-11 13:20:05   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 115, in assert_process_still_running
2024-02-11 13:20:05     raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
2024-02-11 13:20:05 selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /root/.local/share/undetected_chromedriver/undetected_chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 255
```

I am trying to scrape the website using those options:

```
def set_undetected_chrome_options() -> Options:
    chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    return chrome_options

def scrape_pararius(logger):
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=set_undetected_chrome_options())

    driver.get(SEARCH_URL)
    sleep(7)
    page_source = driver.page_source

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")
    properties = soup.find_all("li", class_="search-list__item search-list__item--listing")
```

This is how I build my Docker image:

```
# Use Python 3.10 Alpine image
FROM python:3.10-alpine

# Update apk repositories
RUN echo "http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
    echo "http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories

# Install Chrome and ChromeDriver
# install chromedriver
RUN apk update
RUN apk add chromium chromium-chromedriver

# Upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# Install Selenium
RUN pip install selenium undetected-chromedriver

# Set the working directory in the container to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Run main.py when the container launches
CMD ["python3", "-u", "main.py" ]
```

How to prevent it from crashing in the docker container? I can run it with a normal
`webdriver.Chrome()`, but I want to use the undetectable one.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try commenting out your Chrome Options and see if it works?

```
def set_undetected_chrome_options() -> Options:
    #chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    #chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    #chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    #chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    #chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    return chrome_options
```

The UC driver has some of these options built in but it is hard to tell which ones.  Plus if you tweak the driver options you may undo some of the techniques used to remain undetected.

Also here is the way I call the driver:

```
driver = uc.Chrome(headless=True,use_subprocess=True, options=chrome_options)
```

Hope that helps